# How to set KryoSerializer in Pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

i'm new to Pyspark Please help me  with it:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("FlightDelayRDD").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setSystemProperty("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
sc.setSystemProperty("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", "6")
sc.setSystemProperty("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", "6")
sc.setSystemProperty("spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout", "0.5s")
sc.setSystemProperty("spark.speculation", "true")
```

I want to set KryoSerializer in pyspark like i configured above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From official docs:](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html)

**Since Spark 2.0.0, we internally use Kryo serializer when shuffling RDDs with simple types, arrays of simple types, or string type.**

`To set Kryo serializer:`

```
sc.setSystemProperty("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
```

---

To check:

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.serializer")

#u'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer'
```

Comment: I already tried it. Please tell me how to check that the pyspark is using KryoSerializer only not java serializer.